the version of this app may be old turn off auto update for this app to keep it from getting updated, unable to install on Android 14
I compile my app with target version android 14 (API level 34 ). When I release my app for internal testing, I am getting this error  while trying to download the app through internal testing link "the version of this app may be old turn off auto update for this app to keep it from getting updated". following are my scenarios

APK direct install through adb on new (api level 14) or old(api <14) works fine
Through internal testing link on old device warning message appear , but allow to install
Through internal testing link on new devices warning message appear no option to install

what could be the possible issues.
